# positioning 4 boxes with text in footer

Tags: html, css, block, footer

i want to place 4 rectancles with text in my website

something like this (blue is the color that specifies them!

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/42/983f.jpg/

and the real footer looks like this

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/aygh.jpg/

area with grey is the area with the links down

here is what i have

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer" id="footer">
    <p>
    <a href="#">About Us</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">Privacy</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">Advertise with us</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">Careers</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#footer
{   
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    color: White;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height:normal;
    margin: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1em;
    clear: both;
    height: 10%;
}

#footer p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 600px;

}


#footer a{
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin: 20px;
}

#footer span {
    bottom: 5px;
}
```

**i dont want to change the**

```
    <p>
    <a href="#">About Us</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">Terms and Conditions</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">Privacy</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">FAQ</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">Advertise with us</a><span>|</span>
    <a href="#">Careers</a>
    </p>
```

**i want to add another div with 4 sqare boxes  with positions left, center-left, center-right and right**

Comment: noone? i need your help

Answer (score 0):

if you want the links to render horizontally across the page you can apply the following css.

```
div a
{
    display:inline;
    border:1px solid #000;
    padding:5px;
    margin:auto;
    bottom:0px;
}
.footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}
```

get rid of the `<p>` tag it is not needed

You can style the rest as needed. If you are looking for something more particular please update your question with specifics

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlcrews/dmFhz/)

Comment: thank you very much but i dont want to change **this** code...i wanna know how to add to footer 4 rectancles with text inside them..!!!

Comment: I have updated the fiddle if you want to just add a border around each link you can do so using the border style. There are other options too such as using div elements. TO position the elements at the bottom of a page set the div element footer to position absolute and bottom at 0px. I have updated the fiddle to show a working example.